# JQuery append is not working inside a JQuery click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I am trying to append a logo in a RichText editor immediately after the user hits "Go" and before the new page loads.

```
$('#Go').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.get(url, function(data) {
        var html = '<img src="' + data + '" width=100px height=100px></img>';
        $('.EditorFrame').contents().find('body').append(html);
    });
});
```

Just as I hit "Go", the image briefly appears in the editor before the new page is loaded. The new page - which shows nothing but the result of our editing comes out *blank*! I have tried this with plain text as well - same story.

I have tried hard to debug. For instance, putting:

```
console.log($('.EditorFrame').contents().find('img'));
```

immediately after the append line, does print out the img tag!

Interestingly, when I copy/paste the same code in the console and then press "Go", everything works as normal and I can see the image, text whatever I put in the editor.

I am using the latest Google Chrome for my labors.

Comment: does it work if you change `></img>` to `/>`. Images are self-closing tags

Comment: "Just as I hit "Go", the image briefly appears in the editor before the new page is loaded."

What do you mean "new page is loaded?" Any changes made to the current DOM will be lost once a new page is loaded - including during any postbacks.

It may be worth ensuring that your button has "type='button'" specified on it, to make sure you're not accidentally posting your form back to the server.

Comment: If `#Go` is a `type="submit"` button, then the `<form>`'s `'submit'` event is what needs `e.preventDefault()`. The `'click'` event alone isn't what causes the navigation.

Comment: ...you might remove the `action` from your form (assuming as others have said that this button is in a form)

Comment: Thanks all. The fundamental problem here is that the same code is running perfectly fine in the console and yet not in the script. In this, I believe @rob-m is pointing in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

You are racing your async `get` method and next page load. You probably should return false in your click handler and go to the next page (if that's what you desire) in the success callback of your `get` request:

```
$('#Go').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.get(url, function(data) {
        var html = '<img src="' + data + '" width="100" height="100"></img>';
        $('.EditorFrame').contents().find('body').append(html);
        // go to next page here
    });
    return false;
});
```

Also, width and height attributes should not have "px" and should just be numeric values

Comment: Wonderful. One little problem though. In order to go to the next page, I am having to trigger the click event. But before that, I have to 'off' the handler least we get stuck in the handler trigger loop ---

    $('#Go').off('click').click();

Interestingly, the click event does not fire here. I am having to manually click the #Go button. 

I would really appreciate if you could bail me out again.